# Check if all values of a map are true

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have one `Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();`.
Consider there are five keys in it.

```
map.put("A", true);
map.put("B", true);
map.put("C", false);
map.put("D", true);
map.put("E", true);
```

I need to set one boolean flag as true if all the values in the above map are true.
If any value is false then i need to set boolean flag as false

I can iterate this map and do it like old ways but i want to know how can i do this in a single line by streaming on this map.

Comment: “The old way” would be `!map.containsValue(false)`, not to write a loop. So for this specific task, using the Stream API is not an improvement.

Answer (score 12):

you can use `allMatch`

```
boolean flag = map.values().stream().allMatch(x -> x);
```

There is a catch for `allMatch`. If the collection is empty, then `allMatch` will return **true**

So if you want to set flag to true if map is not empty and all values are true then;

```
boolean flag = !map.isEmpty() && map.values().stream().allMatch(x -> x);
```

or as @Holger suggested

```
boolean flag = !map.containsValue(false)
```

Comment: Or just `!map.containsValue(false)`.

Comment: @Holger: That is the best solution that has been posted! You should it into an answer!

Answer (score 6):

I have another solution. It assumes `map` is not empty and does not contain any `null`s. If that assumption is correct we can just use this:

```
boolean flag = ! map.values().contains(false);
```

Ok - it does not use streams ...

Comment: and even simpler: `!map.containsValue(false)`.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with the "old way". But if you insist, you could go over all your `Map#values` and use `Stream#allMatch`.

```
boolean allTrue = map.values().stream().allMatch(v -> v);
```

Comment: I am trying to think on advantages and disadvantages. it seems "old way" is more readable and backward compatible.

Answer (score 3):

`boolean result = !map.values().stream().anyMatch(Boolean.FALSE::equals);` will do.

Comment: (`Boolean.FALSE::equals` can obviously be replaced by `x -> !x`, but especially in context of an expression used to filter a value by condition, I consider `Boolean.FALSE::equals` more intuitive to read)

Comment: `Boolean.FALSE::equals` has another advantage: It will neither generate an anonymous class nor instantiate an additional object.

Comment: @DietmarHöhmann There will be a `Predicate` generated at runtime for `Boolean.FALSE::equals` the same way as for `x -> !x`.

Comment: @Holger thanks for the hint. Now I've learned a lot about lambda expressions. I'd been told `x -> !x` is little more than syntax sugar for `new Predicate<Boolean>() { ... }`. Obviously things are quite more sophisticated

Answer (score 0):

Just to give another solution :

```
boolean result = map.values().stream().reduce(true, Boolean::logicalAnd);
```

Comment: Interesting one, but less efficient. While `allMatch` as well as `anyMatch` short-circruit, reduce will not.